# Input field does not display value + text alignment issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, input-field

I'm trying to implement active text input field. You drop the file to it, and field should display dropped file's name. Pretty easy task, huh. Here is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/zmej/jers8hf6/4/

- **1st problem:** if filename is longer than field can display, user will see only beginning of filename. I've tried to use CSS property `text-align=right` but it does apply **only to text which is entered by hand**. How can I insist on displaying value' tail, always?
- **2nd problem:** after entering any text by hand, field **refuses** to display value. Here are the steps to reproduce: click on field, press any key, drop file to the field. Field content isn't changed, although `value` attribute was changed indeed! Just the field hasn't displayed it's new value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using set attribute for value, it is adding the `value=”something”` to the HTML input element. Which means it is setting the initial value which is always overridden by any manual input.

And for scrolling to the end, you can use JS `scrollLeft` and set it to a value in pixels greater than the width of the input element.

So, replacing

```
el.setAttribute('value', f.name);
```

in your JavaScript with

```
el.value = f.name;
el.scrollLeft = 1000;
```

will solve both issues.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm.

Comment: ...but why?  
I understand scrollLeft thing, but what's the difference between `el.value = 'something'` and `el.setAttribute('value', 'something')`?

Comment: I added an explanation. Let me know if it's not clear.

Comment: Just as an aside, you should use your original variable ```z``` like in @harry 's answer, rather than getting the element from DOM again.

Comment: Well, actually the code is more complex than this jsfiddle example. I've just forgot to reuse `z` variable here while extracting the core of the problem to display. :)

Answer (score 1):

For problem #1 you can use .focus() and it will set the cursor in the end.

For #2 you can use `getData` try this

```js
const z = document.getElementById('id');

z.addEventListener('drop', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const value = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  z.value= value;
  z.focus();
});
```